# Getting oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection, need oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database inside a Java application running on WebSphere. I need to be able to create an array descriptor to use in a call to a procedure.

The code looks like this:

```
Connection conn=null;
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor;
Connection tmpCon = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
conn =  WSCallHelper.getNativeConnection(tmpCon);
arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("t_my_array",conn);
IDs = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, list.toArray());
```

The line that calls `ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor` throws a class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:149)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:115)
```

Walking through this with the debugger, I can see that `conn` is definitely a `oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection`. The problem is I can't actually reference `LogicalConnection` in my code because that class is not public, so I can't just do something like this:

```
arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("t_my_array",((LogicalConnection)conn).getWrapper());
```

.

And this:

```
arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("t_my_array",((oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)conn).getWrapper());
```

also returns a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection
```

I need to have an `OracleConnection` object, but I can't seem to get one from the `LogicalConnection` that gets returned to me. Has anyone ever seen this before? I feel I'm missing something really obvious here, but maybe I just need another cup of coffee...

Comment: A couple of Google hits suggest that incompatible drivers might cause this. Do you have an earlier ojdbc version somewhere in your WebSphere set-up, or somewhere in your classpath, or packaged in your application?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Interesting idea. I don't think I have a different version of the ojdbc library, but I'll have a look. The application was otherwise working fine until I started writing code to manually pass an array to a procedure.

Comment: @AlexPoole: It looks like you were right!

Comment: Well, Google and the Oracle Forums were right... *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Wanna post the link you found that gave you the idea?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection+incompatible+with+oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en); the first hits at the time were [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2608871), [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2509050) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014950314). Seemed like enough similarity to suggest you might have the same issue. (The fourth hit was this question *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks! I don't think those showed up the first time I did the search. Initially, I got mostly IBM results, but I had a different search string, included the word "WebSphere".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alex Poole pointed me in the right direction. Maven was including an Oracle jar, version 10.2.0.1.0, and WebSphere had the same jar, but version 10.2.0.4.0.

After fixing the POM so that the 10.2.0.1.0 version jar didn't get deployed, the problem seems to be resolved.