# Pass Array/Table Oracle type using LogicalConnection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, messagebroker

I have Oracle procedures that takes input a user-defined Type. UDT is an array of Object(Another UDT). Below are the Type declarations. IBM Integration Bus JDBC Configurable Service is used to get the LogicalConnection and it always gives the LogicalConnection.

```
create or replace Type R_OpenCloseRecords as Object(VSerial_No  number, VError_Code varchar2(2), VReason varchar2(255), VStatus char(1)); 
create or replace Type T_OpenCloseType as varray(100) of R_OpenCloseRecords ; 


procedure UpdateOpenCloseRecord(VOpenCloseType in T_OpenCloseType);
```

I have also tried the above with table of records.

I have tried the above scenario with java oracle types ArrayDescriptor and StructDescriptor. But it returns with this exception: oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

If i use java.sql.Struct it works fine for Object type, but the createArrayOf method fails with exception: Unsupported Feature.

Below is my java code snippet:

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call " + schemaPackageName + ".UpdateOpenCloseRecord(?)}");          
  //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER); 
  callableStatement.setQueryTimeout(timeOut); 

  //      StructDescriptor R_OpenCloseRecords = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("R_OpenCloseRecords", connection); 
  //      Object[] arrayObjectRecord = { data.getSerialNo(), data.getErrorCode(), data.getReason(), data.getStatus() }; 
  //      STRUCT RecordStruct = new STRUCT(R_OpenCloseRecords, connection, arrayObjectRecord ); 

  Object[] arrayObjectRecord = { Integer.parseInt(data.getSerialNo()), data.getErrorCode(), data.getReason(), data.getStatus() }; 
  Struct recordStruct = connection.createStruct((schemaName+ ".R_OpenCloseRecords").toUpperCase(), arrayObjectRecord); 

  //      STRUCT[] arrayObjectTable = {RecordStruct}; 
  //      ArrayDescriptor T_OpenCloseType = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( 
  //            schemaPackageName+ ".T_OpenCloseType", connection); 
  //      VOpenCloseArray = new ARRAY(T_OpenCloseType, connection, arrayObjectTable); 

  Object[] arrayObjectTable = {recordStruct}; 

  callableStatement.setObject(1,connection.createArrayOf((schemaName+ ".T_OpenCloseType").toUpperCase(),  arrayObjectTable) ); 
  //callableStatement.setObject(1, arrayObjectTable, Types.ARRAY); 
  //callableStatement.setArray(1,VOpenCloseArray); 
  callableStatement.execute();
```

You may see the use of descriptors in comments. Connection is acquired using getJDBCType4Connection of MbJavaComputeNode.

Awaiting your reply.

Comment: This may be due to a conflict with two different versions of `ojdbc` jar in the `classpath`. Probably one that comes with your app server, and other with your project!

Comment: ojdbc referenced within the application and on application server (IBM Integration Bus JDBC Configurable Service) is same when i use oracle types. Without descriptors i don't need the jar reference and the same error happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269951/getting-oracle-jdbc-driver-logicalconnection-need-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by externally referencing the ojdbc jar which actually doesn't include the jar within the bar file.