# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, websphere

I'm fighing with this error almost all day.

What I have:

Websphere 8.5.5,
configured data provider(with classpath pointed to a separately placed ojdbc6_g-11.2.0.2.0.jar), with isolatied mode On
war application with ojdbc6_g-11.2.0.2.0.jar driver inside it.

I found next one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269951/getting-oracle-jdbc-driver-logicalconnection-need-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection) but
I don't understand a solution with deletion jar from an application.

If I delete it, I get NoClassDefFoundError. Otherwise I get 'java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection' If i remove it from dataprovider classpath then datasource brokes.

I've made a search for all OracleConnection.class inside Websphere and found them only inside my application.

pls, help..

Comment: Delete it from the .war application and leave it in the Websphere library directory.

Comment: mm, could you specify in what dirrectory exactly? I mean, how can I point war where to look it?

Comment: Do you need two different versions of the driver? The easy solution would be to ensure they are the same version – Alex Motley 9 hours ago

why different? they are the same

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Enought just remove ojdbc jar from dataprovider and war application, and point to it in ProcessDefinition->jvm